# Python3 String Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have three strings, as follow:

```
string1 = 'dddlll'
string2 = 'ddlldds'
string3 = 'lllllddsss'
```

I wanna get the results like that:

```
result1 = 'd3l3'  # The first '3' stands for the number of 'd', and the second '3' stands for the number of 'l' 
result2 = 'd2l2d2s1' 
result3 = 'l5d2s3'
```

Could somebody help me make this out in Python3? I'll be really thankful for your help!

Comment: edit your post, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular case I would say you need a function that iterates over the word, you could use:

```
def letter_counter(string):
    endstring = ''
    prev_letter = ''
    counter = ''
    for letter in string + str(0):
        if prev_letter != letter:
            endstring = endstring + prev_letter + str(counter)
            prev_letter = letter
            counter = 1
        else:
            counter += 1
    return endstring

letter_counter(string1)
'd3l3'
```

If you would only want each letter with the counts then you could use `collections.Counter` and create a custom function like:

```
from collections import Counter
def letter_counter(string):
    endstring = ''
    for k,v in Counter(string).items():
        endstring = endstring + k +  str(v)
    return endstring

letter_counter(string1)
'd3l3'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have tried in Pycharm, string1 works! However, the result of strings2 is d4l2s1, which doesn't match my ideal result.  Counter can statistics the number of the same letter no matter they are continue or scattered.

Comment: @pandalai check the edit, you are right about Counter.

Comment: It works! Really appreciate it for your help! Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! Accept the answer if it solved the question